# Error con el commando runserver de Django

Tags: python, django, ubuntu

Intentando correr el servidor local de Django me aparece el siguiente error en la terminal al correr usando runserver.

Este es el mensaje:

```
    System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
February 28, 2016 - 15:50:27
Django version 1.7.9, using settings 'guacho.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 64, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 168, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 44, in load_middleware
    mw_class = import_string(middleware_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 26, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named security
[28/Feb/2016 15:50:40] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

Por que sucede esto? Como puedo solucionarlo y evitar que vuelva a suceder?

Comment: Puedes especificar que versión de Django es y tu archivo `settings.py`?

Comment: Te esta diciendo que te falta un modulo llamado security, no sera que estas levantando un proyecto con una version incorrecta o no compatible de DJango

Answer (score 3):

Lo que creo que esta pasando es que estas utilizando la versión 1.7.9 de Django para correr un proyecto de Django creado con la versión 1.8, en está version django agrego el middleware `‘django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware’`

AquÍ te dejo 2 alternativas

1. Utilizar una versión de django mayor o igual a la 1.8 **(>= 1.8)**, para instalar a la ultima versión utiliza **pip install django**, y para instalar a una versión especifica **pip install django==1.8**.
2. Borrar `‘django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware’` de la variable MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES del **settings.py**

Answer (score 1):

Si no estoy mal, el modulo que no se encuentra en el proyecto es:

[django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/middleware/#module-django.middleware.security)

`SecurityMiddleware` fue agregado en **Django 1.8**, así que prueba con una versión igual o mayor, o borralo del `settings.py` si definitivamente debes quedarte en **Django 1.7**.

Comment: debo de eliminarlo de settings,py>middleware_classes?

Comment: Si eliminalo de `middleware_classes`, pero intentaste utilizar **Django >= 1.8**?